# Locked Hard Drive

Tags: macos, startup, encryption, recovery

For some reason a recent reboot resulted in a startup screen with a circle with a slash icon instead of the regular Apple icon.

What I tried:

1. Using internet Recovery I used disk utility to fix permissions and repair disk.
2. Also while in Disk Utility I set the disk to decrypt - it accepted my password.
3. While still in Internet Recovery I selected option to re-install - FAILED due to locked disk even though I un-encrypted it.
4. Now it will not take my password to unlock.

I can do nothing at this point.  I think maybe it did not finish decrypting before I tried to re-install OS thus the reason it won't take password.

If I hold down the Option key during startup I do not get the Recovery Partition as an option, even though it does show in Disk Utility.

Question:

Is there any way to unlock?  I have see some information about using sudo commands but when I go to Terminal in recovery it says command is unavailable.

I am using Mavericks.  MacBook Pro.